# Class 'Carbon\Laravel\ServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I've typed the command `composer require uxweb/sweet-alert` in my command prompt to install sweet alert in my Laravel project and an error occurred while installing UxWeb sweet alert.

What could be the cause of this error ?

**Error Message**

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
>   In ProviderRepository.php line 208.
>   Class 'Carbon\Laravel\ServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Please edit your post to replace screenshot by code or result of your command.

Answer (score 2):

There is somewhere where you wrongly imported Carbon class. the correct namespace for Carbon in laravel is

```
Carbon\Carbon
```

you can search your codebase and find the error

OR

you can try deleting vendor folder and reinstall packages again

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete 2 files from laravel/bootstrap file path.
Then composer update